# Example of private route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Private route 53 has nameserver. To use private route 53, do I have to purchase the domain directly and connect to the name server?

There is a cname in public route 53 but not in private route 53. I don't know if you create a domain yourself or how to apply the domain and the name server works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private route 53 does not have a cname and uses it by connecting load balancer to the record.

For example, 'example.local' can be used for communication between servers without purchasing a domain.